# Do OpenMP (OMP_*) environment variables matter during compilation?

Tags: compilation, parallel-processing, fortran, environment-variables, openmp

I am compiling a code in Fotran 90 that uses OpenMP, and I need it to run with, say, OMP_NESTED=false and OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS=2.

My question is, do I need to export the variabes before I compile the code, and then before each run, or should I just export them before I run the code?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, that does not affect the compilation. And even if it did, the OpenMP specifications clearly states what they should do at runtime so that the compile time setting would be overridden.

You just have to export the variables before the run and you can change them for some subsequent run.

Comment: Thanks. I've found it myself already, via checking hashes of my binnaries.

Comment: I've never had anything to do with OpenMP, and I did not even think of cheking the specifications....